# Проблема с определением размеров frame и bounds в альбомной ориентации

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

В общем у меня есть `UIScrollView`,  хочу сделать две странички в этом скроле, чтобы была одна страница (UIView1), а вторая (UIView2). (т.е. что то на подобии постраничной навигации).

Если в `autosizing` изменения по ширине объекта (`UIScrollView`) - выключены, то мне удается сделать все так как я и хочу (за исключением того, что в `iphone 3` скрол вылазит за поля). Но мне нужна поддержка `iphone 3`, поэтому я `autosizing` изменения по ширине - Включаю.

И теперь у меня вообще идет не верное отображение страниц. Дело в том, что `bounds.size.width` и `frame.size.width` выводит НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНЫЕ РАЗМЕРЫ, у меня скрол на всю ширину экрана растянут, а мне эти два свойства выводят ширину 297 (для всех дисплеев `iphone`). Как такое может быть?

Очень прошу помочь, так как основная часть проекта завершена, но возникли проблемы с этим скролом!

Вот ссылка на проект http://dfiles.eu/files/1mbq44nxx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дмитрий, отвечу по порядку:

```
И теперь у меня вообще идет не верное отображение страниц. Дело в том, что bounds.size.width и frame.size.width выводит НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНЫЕ РАЗМЕРЫ, у меня скрол на всю ширину экрана растянут, а мне эти два свойства выводят ширину 297 (для всех дисплеев iphone). Как такое может быть?
```

Как такое может быть, я не знаю. Я считаю, что мы сталкиваемся в данном случае или с багом или с очень недокументрированным аспектом поведения UIViews: я не встречал никакого объяснения следующего поведения нигде в документациях Apple и на SO:

Я создаю новый проект Single view application, и чисто для демонстрации я устанавливаю поддерживаемые ориентации в обе Landscape: левую и правую, я делаю это:

1) В .plist-файле проекта

2) Targets/Summary/Supported interface orientations

3) В MainStoryboard / View Controller Scene / View Controller / Simulated metrics / Orientation

4) В AppDelegate:

```
(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

5) Я добавляю следующий код в ViewController:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");

    NSLog(@"%f", [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
    NSLog(@"%f", [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"%@", self.view);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.bounds.size.width);
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"\nviewDidAppear");

    NSLog(@"%f", [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
    NSLog(@"%f", [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"%@", self.view);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.bounds.size.width);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

@end
```

Вся эта настройка предполагает, что мы хотим используем всю возможную артиллерию для того, чтобы добиться СТОПРОЦЕНТНОЙ Landscape ориентации.

Запускаем проект, вот результат консоли:

```
2013-05-24 00:05:22.998 TestBounds[47844:11303] viewDidLoad
2013-05-24 00:05:22.999 TestBounds[47844:11303] 320.000000
2013-05-24 00:05:23.000 TestBounds[47844:11303] 300.000000
2013-05-24 00:05:23.002 TestBounds[47844:11303] <UIView: 0x8a28970; frame = (20 0; 300 568); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8a28a10>>
2013-05-24 00:05:23.002 TestBounds[47844:11303] 300.000000
2013-05-24 00:05:23.005 TestBounds[47844:11303]
viewDidAppear
2013-05-24 00:05:23.006 TestBounds[47844:11303] 320.000000
2013-05-24 00:05:23.007 TestBounds[47844:11303] 300.000000
2013-05-24 00:05:23.007 TestBounds[47844:11303] <UIView: 0x8a28970; frame = (20 0; 300 568); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8a28a10>>
2013-05-24 00:05:23.008 TestBounds[47844:11303] 300.000000
```

Из этого результата видно, что хотя проект и показывается в альбомной ориентации, програмные его размеры явно выводятся для портретной ориентации, откуда у вас Дмитрий и возникают всевозможные проблемы с определением верных размеров.

Теперь очень интересный момент: меняем в ViewController только одну строку:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

То есть мы как бы говорим контроллеру: "Ты всё равно будешь альбомным, но мы разрешаем тебе вращаться". Хотя здравому смыслу правда и непонятно куда вращаться нашему *ViewController's self.view* после начального запуска в альбомной ориентации, тем не менее мы видим немного другой результат:

```
2013-05-24 00:14:24.919 TestBounds[47898:11303] viewDidLoad
2013-05-24 00:14:24.921 TestBounds[47898:11303] 320.000000
2013-05-24 00:14:24.922 TestBounds[47898:11303] 300.000000
2013-05-24 00:14:24.922 TestBounds[47898:11303] <UIView: 0x758a8b0; frame = (20 0; 300 568); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x758a950>>
2013-05-24 00:14:24.923 TestBounds[47898:11303] 300.000000
2013-05-24 00:14:24.927 TestBounds[47898:11303]
viewDidAppear
2013-05-24 00:14:24.930 TestBounds[47898:11303] 320.000000
2013-05-24 00:14:24.932 TestBounds[47898:11303] 300.000000
2013-05-24 00:14:24.933 TestBounds[47898:11303] <UIView: 0x758a8b0; frame = (20 0; 300 568); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x758a950>>
2013-05-24 00:14:24.933 TestBounds[47898:11303] 568.000000
```

То есть мы видим, что в момент viewDidAppear ширина self.view.bounds **таки стала равна альбомным 568 пикселей**, хотя при этом frame всё равно показывает портретный размер.

Это поведение (с изменённым shouldAutorotate) заставляет меня гадать, что при запуске проекта несмотря на все усилия он запускается в портретной ориентации, и меняет ориентацию и размер self.view лишь на какой-то стадии рендеринга.

Я сталкивался с такой же проблемой значительно в более сложной ситуации и с тех пор решаю эту проблему програмно с помощью функции screenFrame() сообщающей реальный размер рабочей области экрана (о нёй речь пойдёт ниже через абзац)

Отвечая на ваш вопрос, мне пришлось более подробно разобраться в этих тонкостях изменениях размеров и убедиться на примере простейшего приложения в странностях поведения Xcode.

**я безусловно расцениваю такое поведение как баг, если только не появится некто способный объяснить, как возможно, что при всех возможных опциях настройки ориентации на альбомную мы наблюдаем неадекватное масштабирование размеров view даже в самых простых случаях ViewController и его view, кроме того мы наблюдаем попытки Xcode вращать налету view из портретной ориентации в альбомную**.

Вот ссылки со SO: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522672/getting-the-correct-bounds-of-uiviewcontrollers-view), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916939/how-do-i-set-the-first-uiviewcontrollers-view-to-autoresize?rq=1), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488506/ipad-childviews-still-see-incorrect-bounds-in-landscape-mode-even-in-viewdidappe), которые в совокупности указали на

- тот факт, что с размеры view могут отличаться в viewDidLoad и viewDidAppear
- советы опираться на размеры [UIScreen mainScreen]
- советы изменять размеры фреймов программно, игнорируя настройки Xcode.

**Текущий код, который мне позволяет обходить подобные и многие проблемы**

Для определения настоящих размеров экрана (это решение работает для iPhone, возможно для iPad потребуется небольшие изменения) я использую метод (его можно сохранить в файле вроде Screen или Environment):

```
CGRect screenFrame() {
    CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    screenFrame.origin = CGPointZero;

    // Ещё одна странность Apple это то, что точно ориентация определяется через положение statusBar - об этом написаны тонны текста на SO (почему это так, выходит за рамки данного вопроса, просто это работает)
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarOrientation)) {
        CGFloat width = screenFrame.size.width;
        screenFrame.size.width = screenFrame.size.height;
        screenFrame.size.height = width;
    }

    return screenFrame;
}
```

Если добавить эту функцию в viewDidLoad и viewDidAppear:

```
NSLog(@"%f", screenFrame().size.width);
```

Мы увидим, что она выводит размеры адекватно:

```
2013-05-24 00:33:30.628 TestBounds[47965:11303] viewDidLoad
2013-05-24 00:33:30.629 TestBounds[47965:11303] 320.000000
2013-05-24 00:33:30.630 TestBounds[47965:11303] 300.000000
2013-05-24 00:33:30.631 TestBounds[47965:11303] <UIView: 0x711ed60; frame = (20 0; 300 568); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x711edf0>>
2013-05-24 00:33:30.631 TestBounds[47965:11303] 300.000000
2013-05-24 00:33:30.632 TestBounds[47965:11303] 568.000000 // Правильная ширина через screenFrame()
2013-05-24 00:33:30.636 TestBounds[47965:11303] viewDidAppear
2013-05-24 00:33:30.637 TestBounds[47965:11303] 320.000000
2013-05-24 00:33:30.638 TestBounds[47965:11303] 300.000000
2013-05-24 00:33:30.639 TestBounds[47965:11303] <UIView: 0x711ed60; frame = (20 0; 300 568); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x711edf0>>
2013-05-24 00:33:30.640 TestBounds[47965:11303] 568.000000
2013-05-24 00:33:30.641 TestBounds[47965:11303] 568.000000 // Правильная ширина через screenFrame()
```

Ответ получился слишком длинный, поэтому я оставляю за рамками, как конкретно пользуясь этой функцией можно корректно задать все необходимые размеры для ваших subviews, повторю только, что **screenFrame()** вычисляет размер именно рабочей области экрана то есть (экран телефона - ширина статус-полоски), и если вы потестируете **screenFrame()** в сравнении с **UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds** и **UIScreen.mainScreen.applicationFrame**, вы увидите, что только **screenFrame()** даёт размеры внутреннего фрейма экрана адекватные для масштабирования всех внутренних subviews.